# Is it possible to custom draw a ListViewGroup

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am using the System.Windows.Forms.ListView control on .NET 2.0. I know I can set the OwnerDraw property on the ListView to true and then override OnDrawItem to custom draw my ListViewItems. I can also override OnDrawColumnHeader and OnDrawSubItem to draw those components.

However, there is no equivalent "OnDrawGroup" method to override if I want to custom draw my ListViewGroups.

I took a brief look at the messages this control uses and I see there are WM_CUSTOMDRAW and CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT notifications, but I'm wondering is there a way if I handle these native messages to custom draw my ListViewGroups?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible using the built-in mechanism. I think you'd have to drawing everything yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It just can't be done.

You can't do it by drawing everything yourself, or by dropping down to handle `WM_CUSTOMDRAW` or even by using the [undocumented ListView interfaces](http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=studies/windows/shell/comctl32/controls/listview/interfaces/ilistview/index.htm&tx=25) and [used here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/listviewundoc.aspx).

This discussion has come up several times ([here for example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx?msg=3484685#xx3484685xx)). Group headers in a `ListView` are strange beasts. In XP, you could at most set their color (not even their font), but since Vista, there is absolute nothing you can do to them.